# How to change subclass referenced by parent class to have a reference type of subclass?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting, reference-type, derived-types

I have 20 or so event classes that all inherit from EventDto. These subclasses are all being serialized/deserialized (using DataContractJsonSerializer, with each subclass being added as a [KnownType(typeof(subclasstype))] attribute), the deserialization method looks like this:

```
private EventDto DeserializeMessage(byte[] body)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(body);
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(EventDto));

        var eventDto = (EventDto)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

        return eventDto;
    }
```

After deserializing an event, I need to process it based on its type. So I have:

```
public void ProcessMessage(byte[] serializedEvent)
    {
        //Deserialize
        var eventDto = DeserializeMessage(serializedEvent);

        //Process
        Process(eventDto);
    }

public void Process(EventDto eventDto)
    {
        //Do nothing
    }

    public void Process(EventDtoSubclass1 eventDto)
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public void Process(EventDtoSubclass2 eventDto)
    {
        //Do something different
    }
```

The problem is that eventDto in ProcessMessage() has a reference type of EventDto, so the Process() method called is always the same. I need to be able to distinguish between the different subclasses of EventDto and call the appropriate method.

Is there any way to change the type of eventDto in ProcessMessage() from EventDto to its actual derived type (say, of EventDtoSubclass2)?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to change the type of eventDto in ProcessMessage() from EventDto to its actual derived type (say, of EventDtoSubclass2)?

No. You either know the type ahead of time (and can either cast it or use it as a generic type parameter or whatever) or you have to detect it after the fact and branch on it. Since it appears you don't know ahead of time what you're getting, then you need to detect it and branch on it (and by that I mean using `is`/`as` or `GetType`/`typeof` or whatever your favorite method of checking is).

As somewhat of an alternative, if you can change your EventDto-derived classes, you could potentially add a virtual Process function to the base class with overriden versions in each derived class that do the right thing. That depends on what Process actually does, though.

**Edit:** Since I4V said that it wouldn't work, I'm going to put a complete program here showing what I mean for my alternative. Like I said multiple times, unless we know what Process needs to do we don't know if this will truly work for the OP. But it does work in principle.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SOTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program program = new Program();

            EventDtoA a = new EventDtoA() { AProperty = 0, BaseProperty = -1 };
            EventDtoB b = new EventDtoB() { BProperty = 1, BaseProperty = -1 };
            EventDtoC c = new EventDtoC() { CProperty = 2, BaseProperty = -1 };

            var aBytes = program.SerializeMessage(a);
            var bBytes = program.SerializeMessage(b);
            var cBytes = program.SerializeMessage(c);

            var aString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(aBytes);

            EventDto aNew = program.DeserializeMessage(aBytes);
            EventDto bNew = program.DeserializeMessage(bBytes);
            EventDto cNew = program.DeserializeMessage(cBytes);

            aNew.Process();
            bNew.Process();
            cNew.Process();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private byte[] SerializeMessage(EventDto eventDto)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(EventDto));
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, eventDto);
            var tempBytes = new Byte[stream.Length];
            Array.Copy(stream.GetBuffer(), tempBytes, stream.Length);
            return tempBytes;
        }

        private EventDto DeserializeMessage(byte[] body)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream(body);
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(EventDto));

            var eventDto = (EventDto)serializer.ReadObject(stream);

            return eventDto;
        }

        public void ProcessMessage(byte[] serializedEvent)
        {
            //Deserialize
            var eventDto = DeserializeMessage(serializedEvent);

            //Process
            eventDto.Process();
        }


    }

    [KnownType(typeof(EventDtoA))]
    [KnownType(typeof(EventDtoB))]
    [KnownType(typeof(EventDtoC))]
    public class EventDto
    {
        public virtual void Process() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From EventDto Base Class");
        }

        public int BaseProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventDtoA : EventDto
    {
        public override void Process()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From EventDto A");
        }

        public int AProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventDtoB : EventDto
    {
        public override void Process()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From EventDto B");
        }

        public int BProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventDtoC : EventDto
    {
        public override void Process()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("From EventDto C");
        }

        public int CProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
From EventDto A 
From EventDto B 
From EventDto C
```

Comment: add **virtual** Process method, that is

Comment: True. I added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Everything was good till the *alternative* . **-1** (I am ready to remove the -1 if you can show how it would work)

Comment: Pardon? Chris Hardie's answer is my alternative. I can't really flesh it out any more than that without knowing more about what Process does and what EventDto is.

Comment: Ok, I'm lost. I don't see why it wouldn't work. Can you show me why?

Comment: @I4V - I added a complete program. Can you please explain why it wouldn't work (other than if Process does something that can't be encapsulated that way)? I'm very curious now.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the `is` operator.

```
public void Process(EventDto eventDto)
{
   //Do nothing
   if (eventDto is EventDtoSubclass1)
   {
       // do something   
   }
   else if (eventDto is EventDtoSubclass2)
   {
       // do something else
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing too much about your code, is there an opportunity to rework things slightly from an architectural point of view?

To my mind, you could use a variant of the Command pattern, and have the eventDTO objects be responsible for their own processing.

```
public interface IEventDTO{
     void Process();
}

public class EventDTO1 : IEventDTO{
    public void Process(){
        //Glorious codde!
    }
}

public class EventDTO2 : IEventDTO{
   public void Process(){
        //More glorious code!!
   }
}
```

Then you could have a processor that needs not concern itself with the implementation details of processing all the different EventDTOs. In future, if you ever need to add more EventDTOs, the processor would be insulated from any change.

```
public class Processor{
     public void Process(IEventDTO eventDTO){
          eventDTO.Process();
     }
}
```

This was written on the fly, so excuse any errors. Also excuse any naivete on my part for coming up with this based on very little insight to your application and it doesn't fit the bill :)

**EDIT**

I may be a little tired here. If you wouldn't want to attach a method to a dto, which is perfectly understandable, we could create a IEventProcessor interface and use a factory to create instances of implementing types, and use those for processing:

```
public IEventProcessor GetEventProcessor(IEventDTO eventDTO){
      if(eventDTO is EventDTO1)
            return new EventProcessor1();

      if(eventDTO is EvenetDTO2)
            return new EventProcessor2();
}
```